# communicate between subscriptions in azure

Tags: networking, azure, vpn, subscriptions

I have an MSDN and Pay-As-You-Go subscription. Unfortunately, you can't set up one network that works between the two from what I can tell. Currently, I have my VPN setup on the MSDN subscription, but when I start rolling out production virtual machines to 6-month or 12-month pay subscriptions I don't see any other way for my vm's between subscriptions to communicate unless I setup another VPN so they come back to our on-premises and then back to the subscription network the vm was setup under.
How is everyone else doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Correct, a virtual network is currently limited to the scope of a single subscription. This is definately something we're looking to make better soon.

For the time being, you'll need to set up multiple VPN tunnels if you want to divide your Azure-hosted resources across multiple subscriptions.

Comment: `This is definately something we're looking to make better soon.` do you have an estimate for `soon` ? ;)

Comment: They must have redefined 'soon'.